# NGramIndex building and questioning

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I tried to implement an indexbased textsearch with lucene 4.3.1. The code is below. I created the index with au NGramTokenyzer because I would like to find searchresults which are too far away for the FuzzyQuery. 
I have two problems with my solution. The first is that i don't understand why it finds some things but others not. E.g. if I look for "Buter", "utter" or "Bute" it finds "Butter", but if I look for "Btter" there's no Result. Is there an error in my implementation, what should i make different?
Also I would like that it always gives me (e.g.) 10 results for each query. Is this eaven achievable with my code, or what would I need to change to get this 10 results?

Here's the code:

```
public LuceneIndex() throws IOException{
    File dir = new File(indexDirectoryPath);
    index = FSDirectory.open(dir);
    analyzer = new NGramAnalyzer();
    config = new IndexWriterConfig(luceneVersion, analyzer);
    indexWriter = new IndexWriter(index, config);
    reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(dir));
    searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    queryParser = new QueryParser(luceneVersion, "label", new NGramAnalyzer());


}

/**
 *  building the index 
 * @param graph
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void makeIndex(MyGraph graph) throws IOException {
    FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
    fieldType.setTokenized(true);

    //read the items that should be indexed
    ArrayList<String> DbList = Helper.readListFromFileDb(indexFilePath);
    for (String word : DbList) {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("label", word, Field.Store.YES));
        indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
    }

    indexWriter.close();

}


public void searchIndexWithQueryParser(String searchString, int numberOfResults) throws IOException, ParseException {
System.out.println("Searching for '" + searchString + "' using QueryParser");

Query query = queryParser.parse(searchString);

System.out.println(query.toString());


TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, numberOfResults);
ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;

//just to see some output...
int i = 0;

Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
String label = doc.get("label");

System.out.println(label);
}
```

Edit: Code for the NGramAnalyzer

```
public class NGramAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

int minGram = 2;
int maxGram = 2;



@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {

    Tokenizer source = new NGramTokenizer(reader, minGram, maxGram);
    CharArraySet charArraySet = StopFilter.makeStopSet(Version.LUCENE_43,
            FoodProductBlackList.blackList, true);
    TokenStream filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_43, source, charArraySet);

    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
}
}
```

Comment: I assume `NGramAnalyzer` is something you implemented, right?  Could you provide source for it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I added the code to my question.